# Convert a Stream of Data to a set of object

Tags: java, java-8

I'm new to java 8 streams and have a question
I have a stream of data made up of like this

```
RequestObject {
    String Name;
    Long timestamp;
    Set<String> data;
}
```

I want to stream this data and process it and count the names as well as the pct of times it appears.

My resultant object is

```
ProcessedData {
   String name; //request object name
   float pct; //percentage of times it appears in all the stream
   int count; count of times it appears
}
```

I'm not sure if I should use reduce or collect and how that might look.

```
Set<ProcessedData> result = sourceData.stream().collect/reduce....
```

Comment: how do you calculate pct? Can you give a simple example of input / output?

Comment: totalOfName/totalOfAllNames. In java pre 8 I would do it something like this. assuming the data I was processing was in a map  If the data resulted in a map<String,Int>  For(String name:resultantData.getKeySet()){ count = resultantData.get(name); total+=count;} then do the pct calc or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's a `getName()` method in your `RequestObject` class, you could do it with [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`Collectors.counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) as follows:

```
Map<String, Long> map = sourceData.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        RequestObject::getName, 
        Collectors.counting()));
```

In that map, you have all the info you need. To get the % for a given name, simply do `(float) byName.get("GIVEN_NAME") * 100.0 / (float) sourceData.size()`. To do it for every name, iterate over the map and create an instance of your `ProcessedData` for each entry:

```
Set<ProcessedData> processedData = map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new ProcessedData(
        entry.getKey(), 
        entry.getValue(),
        (float) entry.getValue() * 100.0 / (float) sourceData.size()))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This assumes you have a constructor in `ProcessedData` that accepts `name`, `count` and `pct`.

Comment: Thanks, that works great, I think part of my problem is that I was trying to do it all at once.

Comment: @user1864350 If you want to do the same with only one pass, you'd need to write your own collector. This would add complexity to the solution. Maybe it would be worth having a more complex solution if you couldn't afford having two passes.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about that and assumed I'd have to have my own collector for that case